# how detect string pattern over large collection

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm looking for advice in a very specific domain. 
Here is the story : 
I'm working on my node.js project and the following is a tools that i want to add into mt application.
i've got plenty of URLS (around 20,000), and what i want to do is to cluster similar urls together. 
if two urls are similar, they should be regrouped into the same cluster.

I have already find an interesting algorithm :Simil, that provide the % of similarity between two string: http://www.accessmvp.com/tomvanstiphout/simil.htm

the problem here is to find a "clean" way to iterate the simil algo over my whole list of url (without comparing them all to one another)

the hint i have is to combine the simil algo with some map/reduce. but i don't really find this way obvious.

Does someone have ever done something like this ? What whould be your clue ?

i'll appreciate any kind of help. 
Ostro

Comment: So how is this node.js related?

Comment: sorry i forgot that info, i want to add this into a node.js project

Comment: What you have is a clustering problem. It has **nothing** to do with javascript or node specifically.

Comment: [**natural**](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural) is a good module you could use.